# Applying recursion on 1d-list with parentheses

Tags: regex, parsing, recursion, f#, discriminated-union

I am kinda new to F# and I'm trying to write a simple program that reads a mathematical expression and calculates it.

I was successfully able to calculate expressions like: `"5+3 *3 - 1/2"`, `"10 + 50 /50"` etc. As this is being fairly simple and done by straightforward recursion, I wanted to take it to the next level using other mathematical functions (cos,sin etc.) but . . . I stumbled upon **parentheses** as i can't get an idea of how to recurse on patterns such as "((5+3) * 5) - (4-5)" because this is 1 deminsional list of the so-called *Tokens* (I 'tokenize' the input string with Regex") and the list having outer and inner layers of endless expressions!

This is the code I used for the first prototype of calculations:

```
let rec parseEq (src:Expression) = 
match src with 
| [Int number] -> number
| _ ->
    match decompose src with
    Some(Int head,rest) -> 
        match decompose rest with
            | Some(Plus,  rest) -> head + parseEq rest
            | Some(Minus, rest) -> head - parseEq rest
            | Some(Times, rest) -> head * parseEq rest
            | Some(DevBy, rest) -> head / parseEq rest
            | _ -> failwith "input error"
    | _ -> failwith "input error"
```

Note the *tokens* : Plus,Minus, Int etc. this is the same appraoch im trying to use to calculate the more complex expressions.

**Update**: this is the list I get after tokenization:

```
"((5+5) - 10)" |> tokenize;;
val it : Token list =
[Open; Open; Digit 5.0; Plus; Digit 5.0; Close; Minus; Digit 10.0; Close]
```

**Update** : is there a way that i can 'replace' a segment of the token list to one token of type Token list?
like this:

```
"5 + (3-1)" = [Digit 5; Plus; Open; Digit 3; Minus; Digit 1; Close]
```

becomes:

```
"5 + (3-1)" = [Digit 5; Plus; Expr [Digit 3; Minus; Digit 1]]
```

Any ideas would be helpful, Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest using FParsec which is a parser combinator and look at it's OperatorPrecedenceParser.

Comment: Well, using 3rd-parties wouldn't be much help for me, as i'm trying to learn F# by examples and coding everything from the ground up :)

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks man, that was a good one, I'm still trying to wrap my head around the whole thing :)

Comment: This is a known problem. It's solved with Knuth's [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: @GuyCoder The NHol parser code is overkill for this problem. FParsec is one possible solution, but it won't help OP learn how the actual parsing works (if that is one of his goals). See the link I posted in my previous comment -- that algorithm is designed to solve *this exact problem*.

Comment: @JackP. I looked at that algorithm, it is not the way i want to solve this problem, as i didn't try to implement yet (I will do when i'm out of options). my current try is to find the most nested expression, evaluate it (to a token of type Digit [some result]) and find the next most nested (inner) expr. till there are no nested parenthses in my Token list. I seem to be able to get the most nested expr but i can't replace the evaluated Digit in place of the tokens.

Comment: @GuyCoder I indeed have not read a parsing book, can you suggest any? (expecially a book that explains code more than theory for\in C# or F#)

Comment: @GuyCoder I guess in this field we always learn something new, thats why we are addicted . . . :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to do this you probably need to convert your expression into prefix notation. this requires walking over it and pushing onto stacks until you are ready to take the term, so

for example ((5+5) - 10)

becomes

(+5,5)(-10). then it's simply a matter of going from left to right and evaluating the expressions inline.

Comment: I didn't quite get your idea, but my problem is that I don't know if want (or can) recurse the list from the inner layer or from the outer layer, as working from inside out makes expressions such as ((5-3)^2 + 3) more clear to handle

Comment: so, the idea is sort of inline with how usually compiler treats expressions, what you want is to build an expression tree with the operator as the vertex and the operands as the leafs, with root of the tree being the highest priority operator. then it's a simple matter of walking the tree inorder and collapsing nodes.

Comment: @Alex You're spot on. This technique is known as Knuth's [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is in your DU you add

```
|Bracket of Token list
```

then you change your function to

```
match decompose src with
|Some(Int head,rest) -> 
    match decompose rest with
        | Some(Plus,  rest) -> head + parseEq rest
        | Some(Minus, rest) -> head - parseEq rest
        | Some(Times, rest) -> head * parseEq rest
        | Some(DevBy, rest) -> head / parseEq rest
        | _ -> failwith "input error"
|Some(Bracket b,rest) ->
    let head = parseEq b
    match decompose rest with
        | Some(Plus,  rest) -> head + parseEq rest
        | Some(Minus, rest) -> head - parseEq rest
        | Some(Times, rest) -> head * parseEq rest
        | Some(DevBy, rest) -> head / parseEq rest
        | _ -> failwith "input error"
| _ -> failwith "input error"
```

Comment: I have already included such definition to my                  Token = 
    | Digit of float
    | PRight
    | PLeft
    | Hat
    | Plus
    | Minus
    | Star
    | DevBy
    | Expr of Token list

Comment: But i can't populate that token on the lexing part . . .