# Wrong implementation for unnesting parentheses (in an Expression evaluator)

Tags: parsing, recursion, f#, expression, f#-3.0

Down below I have included my whole program code which a mathematical expression evaluator. I annotated my code with coments to explain everything.

The approach I took is as follow:

first of all, the `lexing` part, which is simply done with Regex and this returns a `Token list`(see type `Token` below).

second: implement a function that takes a Token list and evaluates everything (see function `evalExpr` below) with exception that this expression `(Token list)` is not nested with any parantheses.

then as I mentioned in my [quistion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941084/applying-recursion-on-1d-list-with-parentheses) on how to solve the nested parenthses problem, I couldn't implement a ***good*** function to that, as I have a 1-D list of Token, I found it hard to transform it to a Tree and eval it in a subsequential way so I did the following (see the clumsy `unnest2` function below) :

I try to find the most nested expresion between parentheses and evaluate it to a Token of Digit (value) (see Token type - Digit) then have another function that keeps unnesting the most nested expression till there are no parentheses.

I was testing the function alot with F# Interactive and made changes to function till I got what I wanted:

So my program now can do this : "5+((5-2) + 4)" = "5+(3+4)" = "5+7" = 12 (yeeessss, it worked)

but then when i tested is on this: "4+(5+(3))" = "4+(3)" = "4+3" = 7 -> Note that how the 5 between two 'Open' parentheses is being ignored on the unnesting phase

So I need your help guys to find out whats wrong in the `unnest2` function.

Note that i'm a beginner with F#, so excuse me for my way of trying to solve this, as I have a C# background.

NOTE: A lot of you told me that i need to use the Shunting-yard algorithm, I didn't like it much, i would like to use my own algorithm to solve this

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

// Token types
type Token = 
    | Digit of float
    | Open 
    | Close 
    | Hat
    | Plus
    | Minus
    | Star
    | DivBy
    | Cos
    | Sin
    | Tan
    | Fact
    | Sqrt

let regex pattern = new Regex(pattern)

let tokenRegex = regex @"[0-9]+(\.+\d*)?|\+|\-|\*|\/|\(|\)|\^|cos|sin|tan|sqrt|fact"

// a factorial function along the way
let rec fact n = if n < 2 then 1 else n * fact(n-1)

// The lexing part, pretty straightforward
let tokenize input = 
    [for x in tokenRegex.Matches(input) do
        let token = 
            match x.Value with
            | "+" -> Plus
            | "-" -> Minus
            | "*" -> Star
            | "/" -> DivBy
            | "^" -> Hat
            | "(" -> Open 
            | ")" -> Close
            | "cos" -> Cos
            | "sin" -> Sin
            | "tan" -> Tan
            | "sqrt" -> Sqrt
            | "fact" -> Fact
            | s   -> Digit (float s)
        yield token]


let decompose (src:Token list) = 
    match src with 
    | head::tail -> Some(head,tail)
    | _ -> None

// evaluates a Token list to a float, it calculates an unnested expression!
let rec evalExpr src = 
    match src with
    | [Digit value] -> value
    | _ ->
        match decompose src with
        | Some(Digit tok, rest) ->
            match decompose rest with 
            | Some(Plus, rest) -> tok + evalExpr rest
            | Some(Minus, rest) -> tok - evalExpr rest
            | Some(Star, rest) -> tok * evalExpr rest
            | Some(DivBy, rest) -> tok / evalExpr rest
            | Some(Hat, rest) ->
                match decompose rest with
                    | Some(Digit index,rest) -> evalExpr (Digit(tok**index)::rest)
                    | _ -> failwith "Expected a number after ^"
            | None -> failwith "expected an arthimetic operation (+, -, *, or /) or power (^) after a number"
        | Some(Tan,rest) ->
            match rest with
                | [Digit value] -> evalExpr [Digit(tan value)]
                | Digit(value)::rest -> evalExpr (Digit(tan value)::rest)
                | _ -> failwith "Exprected a number after tan"
        | Some(Cos,rest) ->
            match rest with
                | [Digit value] -> evalExpr [Digit(cos value)]
                | Digit(value)::rest -> evalExpr (Digit(cos value)::rest)
                | _ -> failwith "Exprected a number after cos"
        | Some(Sin,rest) ->
            match rest with
                | [Digit value] -> evalExpr [Digit(sin value)]
                | Digit(value)::rest -> evalExpr (Digit(sin value)::rest)
                | _ -> failwith "Exprected a number after sin"     
        | Some(Sqrt,rest) ->
            match rest with
                | [Digit value] -> evalExpr [Digit(sqrt value)]
                | Digit(value)::rest -> evalExpr (Digit(sqrt value)::rest)
                | _ -> failwith "Exprected a number after sqaure root"
        | Some(Fact,rest) ->
            match rest with
                | [Digit value] -> evalExpr [Digit(float (fact (int value)))]
                | Digit(value)::rest -> evalExpr (Digit(float (fact (int value)))::rest)
                | _ -> failwith "Exprected a number after factorial"          
        | _ -> failwith "input error"

// returns a Token type of Digit with an evaluated Token list
let parseExpr src = 
    src |> evalExpr |> Digit 

// checks if a Token list has some token
let has (list:Token list) tok =
    list |> List.exists (fun x -> x = tok)

let rev list = 
    List.rev list

// here it is, pretty clumsy implementation on finding 
// the most nested expression, and evaluating it with 'parseExpr'
// "5+((9-4)+3)" becomes "5+(5+3)"
let rec unnest2 src acc (src2:Token list) = 
    match src with 
    | [] -> []
    | [Close] -> 
        if src2.Head = Open then (rev src2.Tail) @ [parseExpr (rev acc)] 
        else (rev src2) @ [parseExpr (rev acc)]
    | Close::rest -> 
        if src2.Head = Open then (rev src2.Tail) @ [parseExpr (rev acc)] @ rest
        else (rev src2) @ [parseExpr (rev acc)] @ rest
    | tok::rest ->
        match tok with
        | token -> 
            if (src2 |> has <| Open) && token <> Open then unnest2 rest (token::acc) src2
            else unnest2 rest [] (token::src2)

// wrapper function
let unnest src =
    unnest2 src [] []

// if a Token list has 'Open' (open parentheses) then keep unnesting it 
let rec parse2 src =
    if src |> has <| Open then parse2 (unnest src)
    else evalExpr src

// wrapper function
let parse input = 
    input |> tokenize |> parse2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that you may not be doing that you should is do the work with pen and paper to understand the algorithms as described in books, then using test cases build up the functions until you have the entire solution.

You need to step back to your original problem of just numbers and the basic operators +,-,*,/ **without parens** for precedence changing and learn to build [Abstract Syntax Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree).

Once you have the AST properly built, you will see that the parens are not needed in the AST. The parens are still needed in the input for grouping of the operands with the operator for prefix notation.

Then when you are building a proper AST, you can easily evaluate it by walking the tree.

When you start with your input, start with [prefix notation](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_notation), AKA [polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) as this lends itself to directly building trees, in this case AST.

```
Infix  2*3  
Prefix *(2,3)  


AST

   *
  / \
 2   3
```

Note that when using parens they can be used for changing precedence and grouping.  When starting with prefix notation only use parens for grouping and not changing precedence.

Once you get the basic arithmetic operators in prefix notation parsed, converted to an AST and evaluated, you can then add more features such as
1. [Pretty printers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint).
2. [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)
3. [infix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) notation.
4. [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) and parens for changing operator precedence.
5. [Associativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) of operators
6. [Syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)
7. Simplification rules such as x + 0 = x, or x * 1 = x.
8. [Term rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewriting).

Comment: Apperantly, I'm starting this in the wrong direction with my exmaple ... I will start re-writing the program and try to implement this approach. However, it does seem as easy as you explain here! :)

Comment: The quality of being able to set aside a good deal of previous work to make progress is something that has served me well; it takes disciple to do it.

Comment: When you said "when using parens they can be used for changing precedence and grouping. When starting with prefix notation only use parens for grouping and not changing precedence." did you mean when parsing the input, do consider the parens (as tokens) but then when converting it to prefix notation, don't consider them as they will be implicit on evaluation of the prefix 'tree'. Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, you need the parens in the input for prefix notation, but the AST will not have parens in them. Latter when you use parens for changing precedence, the parens for changing precedence will also be in the input with the result of moving the location of the branch in the AST. It is the moving of the branch in the AST which resolves the problem with the parens for precedence and makes evaluation just a walk of the tree. The trick is to get the branches in the right place in the AST to preserve the meaning of the original expression.

Comment: @ZaidAjaj I added the code for both a prefix parser and an infix parser. To do the parens with infix I used the classic BNF factoring to handle the precedence changes with parens. I don't think we mentioned that yet in either question. See [Github](https://github.com/EricGT/ArithmeticExpressionEvaluator)

Comment: Here is an [demonstration](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/Fall12/CSCI-GA.1133-002/notes/InfixToPostfixExamples.pdf) of how to convert infix to postfix, but the conversion from infix to prefix is not much different.

Comment: Thanks for the demo, it is alot easier when you see the what happens to the input with the algorithm, However I have successfully written the algorithm in F# by looking at a Java applet that dynamically demonstrates the workflow of the algorithm (was listed on Wikipedia ext. links) and it was very helpful testing out some expressions, I'm very happy with my parser, didn't use FParsec or something like that. Althought it runs really nice, but I got confused at the end as I didn't implement the right- and left-associativity of operators. Thanks again for your time.